# Serialization of a Weighted Graph

Tags: java, serialization, graph

I am attempting to serialize a weighted graph, and I am running into some issues.

I have an instance of an `UndirectedGraph<T>` which extends `Graph<T>`. The only two fields in `Graph<T>` are:

```
private Map<T,Vertex<T>> vertices;
private int edgeCount;
```

So I have in the class `UndirectedGraph<T>` the following in order to serialize:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
  inputStream.defaultReadObject();
  Map<T,Vertex<T>> vertexList =(Map<T,Vertex<T>>)inputStream.readObject();
  int edgeCount=(Integer)inputStream.readObject();
  super.init(vertexList,edgeCount);
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
  outputStream.defaultWriteObject();
  outputStream.writeObject(super.getVertexList());
  outputStream.writeObject(super.getNumberOfEdges());
}
```

In `Graph<T>` the corresponding methods `getVertexList`, `getNumberOfEdges`, and `init` are as follows:

```
public int getNumberOfEdges(){
  return edgeCount;
}

protected Map<T,Vertex<T>> getVertexList(){
  return vertices;
}

protected void init(Map<T,Vertex<T>> newVertexList, int newEdgeCount){
  if (vertices==null){
     vertices=newVertexList;
     edgeCount=newEdgeCount;
  }
  else{
     throw new IllegalStateException("The graph is already initialized");
  }
}
```

I get an exception when I run it in my main method:

```
try(
     OutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("globalgraph.ser");
     OutputStream buffer=new BufferedOutputStream(file);
     ObjectOutput output=new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
  )
  {
     output.writeObject(globalGraph);
  }
  catch(IOException e){
     System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

The exception I get is "IOException: Vertex$Edge", and I found out it comes from the line `outputStream.writeObject(super.getVertexList());`. Other than that though, I have no idea where it comes from. `Edge` is an inner class of `Vertex<T>`, and `Vertex<T>` impements `Serializable`, and simply uses the methods

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
  inputStream.defaultReadObject();
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
  outputStream.defaultWriteObject();
}
```

to serialize. I've been looking at this for a while and am at a loss as to what could cause this exception. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: adding Vertex and Edge classes

```
public class Vertex<T> implements Serializable{

  private T label;                 //The data within the node
  private ArrayList<Edge> edgeList;//List of edges leaving node
  private boolean visited;          //Denoting whether traversal algorithms have accessed
  private Vertex<T> previousVertex; //Previous vertex for traversal algorithms 
  private double cost;             //cost to get to this vertex from some origin vertex
  private boolean userVisited;


  public Vertex(T vertexLabel){
     label=vertexLabel;
     edgeList=new ArrayList<>();
     visited=false;
     previousVertex=null;
     cost=0;
     userVisited=false;
  }

  //Vertex methods

  protected class Edge{
     //the vertex the edge points to
     private Vertex<T> endVertex;
     //the weight of the edge from the vertex to endVertex
     private double weight;

     private int numberOfEdits;

     protected Edge(Vertex<T> vertex, double edgeWeight){
        endVertex=vertex;
        weight=edgeWeight;
        numberOfEdits=1;
     }

     //Edge methods


   }

  //Iterator inner classes, don't need to serialize these

  //***********Serialization Methods************
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9993882109871L;

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
     inputStream.defaultReadObject();
  }

  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
     outputStream.defaultWriteObject();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your Vertex<T> and Edge classes?

Comment: That `Vertex` implements `Serializable` does not automatically mean that any classes nested in it do, too.  Each class you want to serialize must implement `Serializable`, and must provide for serializing and restoring the state of any non-serializable object it references directly or indirectly via a non-`transient` variable (possibly by delegation).

Comment: Code coming soon, I am in lab right now. @JohnBollinger, even inner classes? I have read that it is bad practices for inner classes to implement Serializable

Comment: @user50210, if you want to serialize instances of an inner class, then either they, too, must implement `Serializable`, or some other object must handle serializing and restoring them.  The default serialization engine will not accept them directly.

Comment: @Mshnik edit made to post Vertex and Edge classes